# is_user_logged_in() return false even when logged in to WordPress?

Tags: api, rest, controller, wordpress

I have a plugin that I created and I want to use the WP rest api controller pattern and extend the api.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: myplugin
* Plugin URI: h...
* Description: A simple plugin ...
* Version: 0.1
* Author: Kamran ...
* Author ....
* License: GPL2

function myplugin_register_endpoints(){

  require_once 'server/controllers/my_ctrl.php';
  $items=new items();
  $items->register_routes();
```

}

add_action('rest_api_init','myplugin_register_endpoints');
   .
   .

I created a class in folder called server/controllers and inside it my_ctrl.php file with a class that extends WP_REST_Controller that looks like this

```
<?php

class items extends WP_REST_Controller {

  /**
  * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
  */

  public function register_routes() {
    $version = '1';
    $namespace = 'my-namespase/v' . $version;
    $base = 'abc';

    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base, array(
        array(
            'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
            'args' => array(
                'id' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return is_numeric( $param ) and ! is_null(get_post($param));//numeric post id value and there is valid post for this id
                    },
                    'sanitize_calback' => 'absint'
                )
            ),
        ),

    ) );

    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base . '/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
        array(
            'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback'        => array( $this, 'create_item' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'create_item_permissions_check' ),
            'args' => array(
                'id' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return is_numeric( $param ) and ! is_null(get_post($param));//numeric post id value and there is valid post for this id
                    },
                    'sanitize_calback' => 'absint'
                )
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::DELETABLE,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'delete_item' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'delete_item_permissions_check' ),
            'args' => array(
                'id' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return is_numeric( $param ) and ! is_null(get_post($param));//numeric post id value and there is valid post for this id
                    },
                    'sanitize_calback' => 'absint'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ) );

    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base . '/schema', array(
        'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_public_item_schema' ),
    ) );

}

function get_items( $request ){
    return new WP_REST_Response( array('message' => "list items"), 200 );
}

function create_item( $request ) {
    .....
    if($author_email==$user_email) {

        return new WP_REST_Response( array('message' => 'success', 200 );

    } else {

       return new WP_Error('my-error', __(' error...','abc'), array( 'status' => 500 ));
    }
}

//Remove vote////////////////////////////////////////////
function delete_item( $request ) {
    ...
    if($author_email==$user_email) {

        return new WP_REST_Response( array('message' => 'success', 200 );

    } else {

       return new WP_Error('my-error', __(' error...','abc'), array( 'status' => 500 ));
  }

}

public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
    return true;
}

public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
        return new WP_Error('login error',__('You are not logged in','KVotes-voting'));
    }
    return true;

}

public function delete_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
    return $this->create_item_permissions_check( $request );
}

protected function prepare_item_for_database( $request ) {
    return array();
}

public function prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request ) {
    return array();
}

public function get_collection_params() {
    return array(
        'page'                   => array(
            'description'        => 'Current page of the collection.',
            'type'               => 'integer',
            'default'            => 1,
            'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
        ),
        'per_page'               => array(
            'description'        => 'Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.',
            'type'               => 'integer',
            'default'            => 10,
            'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
        ),
        'search'                 => array(
            'description'        => 'Limit results to those matching a string.',
            'type'               => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback'  => 'sanitize_text_field',
        ),
    );
}
```

}

I am logged in and I am using cookie authentication with Nonce in my plugin.
when I run my code and debug it with sublime xdebug extension I can see that I indeed hit the end points routes but although I am logged it in the lines: "is_user_logged_in()" = (bool) 0 and therefore the function create_item_permissions_check return new WP_Error(....);and not true;

therefore my rest callback "create_item" is not invoked, I don't understand why is_user_logged_in() return false even when I am logged in.

Comment: You should try to use `empty(wp_get_current_user ())`, just an idea…

Comment: It might have to do with the hooks. I don't know at what point the API is loaded, but my guess is early on in order to keep it snappy. Check to see if the user has been created yet at that point in the hooks cycle.

Comment: Tnx jackr, Loic, I changed my code but I didn't get the desired result, I edited my permission check function:  public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();//Return WP_User (object) with Attribute ID that will show 0 if there is no user.
        if ( $current_user->ID==0) {
            return new WP_Error('login error',__('You are not logged in','KVotes-voting'));
        }
        return true;
    } wp_get_current_user() always return an object with ID of 0, hence the if condition is always false, can give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to send the logged in user info to my custom class as a parameter to the constructor and then use the user data in the permission check function and other functions that needs the user info:

```
class items extends WP_REST_Controller {

  /**
  * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
  */
   private $loged_in;//bool
   private $user;
   public function __construct($logged,$cur_user) {
       = $logged;
    $this->user = $cur_user;
   }

   .
   .
   .

   public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {

       if($this->loged_in!=1){
           return new WP_Error('login error',__('You are not logged in','....'));
       }
       return true;
  }

  .
  .
  .


}
```

And my plugin myplugin_register_endpoints looks as follows:

function myplugin_register_endpoints(){

```
   require_once 'server/controllers/my_ctrl.php';       
   $items=new items(is_user_logged_in(),wp_get_current_user());
   $items->register_routes();
}
```

now when I route to one of the URL's And hit the end points and the check permission is invoked with the needed user data. $this->loged_in!=1 when thew user is not logged in, otherwise the permission check returns true .

Answer (score 0):

I ran into precisely this issue. It seems that the architecturally correct way to handle the problem is for the ajax request to include a nonce. See the references discussed in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299843/161167)